# Error: InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a problem, every time I run my application it gives this error below. I debugged it line by line and saw that the error opens when executing the line "var res = await client.SendAsync(req);"

I've tried everything and I can't find a solution. I've searched everywhere, I've changed from "SendAsync" to everything possible and I can't solve it, I've been trying for 2 days.

**My code:**

```
public async Task ListAsync()
        {
            var client = new HttpClient
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri("https://teste.teste1.com.br")
            };

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-user-email", "victor@teste.com.br");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-api-key", "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGcxYg");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-store-key", "1");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("accept", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
           // client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            HttpRequestMessage req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "/app/Api/V1/Products/list");
            req.Content = new StringContent("Content-Type", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            using var res = await client.SendAsync(req);
            res.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            var responseBody = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var root = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Product>(responseBody);
        }
```

**My index(view):**

```
@model IEnumerable<WebConsumoApi.Models.Product>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h1>Index</h1>

<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.sku)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.description)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.status)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.qty)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.price)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.list_price)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.weight_gross)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.weight_liquid)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.height)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.width)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.length)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.items_per_package)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.brand)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ean)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.sku)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.description)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.status)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.qty)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.price)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.list_price)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.weight_gross)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.weight_liquid)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.height)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.width)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.length)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.items_per_package)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.brand)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ean)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.sku }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.sku }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.sku })
            </td>
        </tr>
}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**My Interface:**

```
using WebConsumoApi.Models;

namespace WebConsumoApi.Interfaces
{
    public interface IProduto
    {
        Task ListAsync();
        Product Create(Product produto);
        Product Update(Product produto);
        Product GetOne(string Codigo);
        Product Delete(string Codigo);

    }
}
```

**EDIT 1:**

ERROR: [ERRO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOzUR.png)

**EDIT 2(CONTROLLER):**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using WebConsumoApi.Interfaces;
using WebConsumoApi.Models;

namespace WebConsumoApi.Controllers
{
    public class ProdutosController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IProduto _IProduto;
        public ProdutosController(IProduto IProduto)
        {
            _IProduto = IProduto;
        }

        // GET: ProdutosController
        public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
        {
            return View(_IProduto.ListAsync());
        }

        // GET: ProdutosController/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(string id)
        {
            return View(_IProduto.GetOne(id));
        }

        // GET: ProdutosController/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: ProdutosController/Create
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(Product collection)
        {
            try
            {
                _IProduto.Create(collection);
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

        // GET: ProdutosController/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(string id)
        {
            return View(_IProduto.GetOne(id));
        }

        // POST: ProdutosController/Edit/5
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id, Product collection)
        {
            try
            {
                _IProduto.Update(collection);
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

        // GET: ProdutosController/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(string id)
        {
            return View(_IProduto.GetOne(id));
        }

        // POST: ProdutosController/Delete/5
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Delete(string id, Product collection)
        {
            try
            {
                _IProduto.Delete(id);
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**My class Product:**

```
namespace WebConsumoApi.Models
{

    public class Product
    {
        public string sku { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public int qty { get; set; }
        public float price { get; set; }
        public float? list_price { get; set; }
        public float weight_gross { get; set; }
        public float weight_liquid { get; set; }
        public int height { get; set; }
        public int width { get; set; }
        public int length { get; set; }
        public string items_per_package { get; set; }
        public string brand { get; set; }
        public string ean { get; set; }
        public object ncm { get; set; }
        public Category[] categories { get; set; }
        public string[] variation_attributes { get; set; }
        public Variation[] variations { get; set; }
        public string[] images { get; set; }
        public Published_Marketplace published_marketplace { get; set; }
        public Marketplace_Offer_Links[] marketplace_offer_links { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should show ony your Index controller action code, all data you posted is irrelevant.

Comment: My method that is running is "my code". I added in EDIT 2 my controller

Answer (score 0):

you have to get data for view, your view model should be like this

```
@model List<WebConsumoApi.Models.Product>
```

and controller

```
        private readonly DbContext _context;
        public ProdutosController( DbContext context)
        {
           _context=context;
        }

      
        public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
        { 
           List<Product> model= await _context.Products.ToListAsync();
            return View(viewModel);
        }
```

and your lambda expressions for the column name should be

```
             <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].sku)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].name)
            </th>
            ... and so on
```

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but I put it exactly the same and it gave an error, would I change something in these parameters?

And in relation to the Model it is giving this error when I change to "List":
Error (active) CS1061 'List<Product>' does not contain a definition for "sku" and could not find any "sku" extension method that accepts a first argument of type 'List<Product>' (you're forgetting to use a directive or assembly reference?)

Comment: @VICTORMARCONISANTOSDEOLIVE You have to show us your Product class too

Comment: Added class product. Thanks for the help my friend

Comment: I changed my model and it worked. Now the controller is giving error. In the DbContext I imported the "Entity". But in the line "List<Product> model= await _context.Products.ToListAsync();" gives error when I put "_context.Product" "Error CS1061 'DbContext' does not contain a definition for "Product" and could not find any extension method "Product" that accepts a first argument of type 'DbContext' (you're forgetting to use a directive or assembly reference?)". I also returned the view, I put "return View(Index)", is that correct? Sorry for so many problems, I'm in learning.

Comment: @VICTORMARCONISANTOSDEOLIVE  at first you have to learn an Entity Framework. How to create databasecontext. After you have to learn how you can inject dbcontext. And only after this you can try to create and fill a view.

Comment: I'm consuming a web api with my api. Do I need to use DbContext anyway? Even without storing data?

Comment: @VICTORMARCONISANTOSDEOLIVE In this case you have to create the code using httpclient to get data from API

Comment: I already got the data, I'm already receiving the data in Json as well as in the "My code" section. But when I get to the line "var res = await client.SendAsync(req);" it returns this error page and does not deserialize.